# script to ping a 'router' from pinging a single hostname

Tags: vbscript, ip-address, ping, router

I am trying to write a script where it will prompt you for a *hostname*, say `222012-DC01` from this it will resolve the *ip address* from *dns* via `ping` or `nslookup`.

It should then modify the *ip address* to ping the router for that site. If the *ip address* was `10.123.2.1` it should ping `10.123.1.1` for the router for that site.

The script should give you an output of **server offline** or **router offline**.

Work in an enviroment looking after several hundred sites, we take ownership of servers but not network incidents such as a router failure.

Your help is much appreciated...

Comment: Do you have a map of the netblocks for each site? Do they all uniformly use the first IP in their block for the router address? If not, this is not doable (and if yes, a couple of example netblock definitions would be helpful). Or is the 10.x.x.x example just a placeholder for what is really a public address in a real block? Or is your network entirely partitioned into /16s in the 10.x.x.x space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the future please post what you have got and tried.
Here is a tested script

```
function get_ip(strTarget)
  set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set objExec = objShell.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & strTarget)
  strPingResults = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
  get_ip = ""
  if InStr(strPingResults, "reply from") then
    wscript.echo VbCrLf & strTarget & " responded to ping."
    set regEx = New RegExp
    regEx.Pattern = "\b\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\.\d{1,3}\b"
    set matches = regEx.Execute(strPingResults)
    if matches.count > 0 then
      get_ip = matches(0)
    end if
  else
    wscript.echo vbCrLf & strTarget & " did not respond to ping."
    wscript.quit 1
  end If
end function

function is_online(strTarget)
  set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
  set objExec = objShell.Exec("ping -n 2 -w 1000 " & strTarget)
  strPingResults = LCase(objExec.StdOut.ReadAll)
  if inStr(strPingResults, "reply from") then
    is_online = true
  else
    is_online = false
  end If
end function

pcname = inputbox( "Give the pc-name to ping:")
ip = get_ip(pcname)
wscript.echo "ip of pc " & pcname & " is " & ip
aIp = split(ip, ".")
aIp(2) = 1
router = join(aIp, ".")
wscript.echo "pinging " & router
if is_online(strTarget) then
  wscript.echo "router is online"
else
  wscript.echo "router is offline"
end if
```